# Date object into a Date object in (mm/dd/yyyy)

Tags: java, date

my class is calling a `Date incomingDate = new Date()` which the doc says is:
*Allocates a Date object and initializes it so that it represents the time at which it was allocated, measured to the nearest millisecond.*

And apparently `incomingDate` looks like:

However I need to pass a the same Date object but in a formatted way (not as a String) in mm/dd/yyyy to print to a csv file.

The `Date` class and the `Formatter` class doesn't help.

Comment: `incomingDate` looks like what?

Comment: What do you mean "formatted way (not as a String)"? How else would you format something?

Comment: Maybe he meant not as in toString?

Comment: You seem to have fallen prey to a common confusion. The `Date` class has a `toString` method, so when you print or log a `Date` instance, or use certain debuggers to examine one, you'll see a formatted string representing it. But the date itself does not have any format. (It also doesn't have any timezone, which is another common point of confusion resulting from the same cause.)

Comment: I don't quite know why you completely ripped out your old question, but that's highly discouraged.  If you have a different question, please ask it in a separate question.

Comment: it was a mistake copying and pasting

Answer (score 2):

You should use `SimpleDateFormat` to format your date

```
Date incomingDate = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(incomingDate )); // sysout or whatever you want (write in your CVS for example)
```

Comment: above gives String not Date object